# PHP Script How to add open in blank page?

Tags: php

What/Where can I add _blank to make this open in a new page/window?

```
 <?php if(of_get_option('facebook_url')){ ?>
 <li class="icon-lists"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('facebook_url'); ?>"><span class="icons-facebook"></span></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You could have just googled "_blank".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add attribute `target="_blank"` in anchor tag.

```
 <li class="icon-lists"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo of_get_option('facebook_url'); ?>"><span class="icons-facebook"></span></a></li>
```